# Write a list of dataframe in an excel file

Tags: r, excel, list, dataframe

Making a list of data frames is easy:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2), y2 = c(6, 5))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)
```

My question is: how could I write `my.list` on a `excel` file, whose sheet are `d1` and `d2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `write.xlsx` in `openxlsx`. It can take a list of multiple data frames as input and turn each data frame into an individual sheet of the final excel file.

```
library(openxlsx)
write.xlsx(my.list, "foo.xlsx", sheetName = c("d1", "d2"))
```

If your list has been named, i.e. `names(my.list)` is not `NULL`, then you can neglect the argument `sheetName` and the sheet names will be set as the list names by default.

Comment: This is the quickest way and consumes less memory when the list is large.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xlsx` package:

```
library(xlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb,"d1") 
sheet2 <- createSheet(wb,"d2")
addDataFrame(my.list[[1]],
                 sheet=sheet1,
                 startRow=1,
                 row.names=FALSE)
addDataFrame(my.list[[2]],
                 sheet=sheet2,
                 startRow=1,
                 row.names=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb,file = "myXlsx.xlsx")
```

Generic way:

```
sheetNames<-c("d1","d2")
library(xlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
for(i in 1:length(my.list)){
  sheetName<- createSheet(wb,sheetNames[i]) #add sheets to excel
  addDataFrame(my.list[[i]],
               sheet=sheetName,
               startRow=1,
               row.names=FALSE)#assign dataframe to sheet
}
saveWorkbook(wb,file = "myXlsx1.xlsx")
```